# Lower bound on cosine function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Let $\theta_1 = \arcsin(\varepsilon)$ be a the inverse sine of a small angle. Let $\theta_2 = \arcsin(\sqrt{1-2\varepsilon^2})$.

Can one lower bound $\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2)$ in terms of $\varepsilon$? I see that $\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2)\rightarrow 0$ when $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ but I am not sure how to calculate how fast it goes to zero.

Any hints on how to solve this would be great!

Comment: Unless I don't understand your question, $\theta_2$ is exactly $\dfrac\pi2-\theta_1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, I missed a 2 in the question. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\sqrt2\epsilon-\epsilon\sqrt{1-2\epsilon^2}\sim(\sqrt2-1)\epsilon.$$